# Erro ao executar metodo POST

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, post, crud

Estou enfrentando um problema em relação ao método POST, ao acionar esse metodo ele insere normalmente no banco de dados, porem a aplicação (node index.js) é finalizada, no prompt de comando recebo esse erro:

**Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client**

ainda no prompt, se refere para a linha:

**at Query._callback (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Backend\index.js:67:13)**

CODIGO POST:

```
router.post('/usuarios', (req, res) =>{
    const nome = req.body.nome.substring(0,255);
    const email = req.body.email.substring(0,255);
    const senha = req.body.senha.substring(0,255);
    execSQLQuery(`INSERT INTO usuario(nome,email,senha) VALUES('${nome}','${email}','${senha}')`, res);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

CODIGO COMPLETO:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();         
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000; //porta padrão
const mysql      = require('mysql');

//configurando o body parser para pegar POSTS mais tarde
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//definindo as rotas
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'Funcionando!' }));

router.get('/filmes/:id?', (req, res) =>{
    let filter = '';
    if(req.params.id) filter = ' WHERE ID=' + parseInt(req.params.id);
    execSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM filme' + filter, res);
});

router.get('/usuarios/:id?', (req, res) =>{
    let filter = '';
    if(req.params.id) filter = ' WHERE ID=' + parseInt(req.params.id);
    execSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM usuario' + filter, res);
});

router.delete('/usuarios/:id', (req, res) =>{
    execSQLQuery('DELETE FROM usuario WHERE ID=' + parseInt(req.params.id), res);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

router.post('/usuarios', (req, res) =>{
    const nome = req.body.nome.substring(0,255);
    const email = req.body.email.substring(0,255);
    const senha = req.body.senha.substring(0,255);
    execSQLQuery(`INSERT INTO usuario(nome,email,senha) VALUES('${nome}','${email}','${senha}')`, res);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

router.patch('/usuarios/:id', (req, res) =>{
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
    const nome = req.body.nome.substring(0,255);
    const email = req.body.email.substring(0,255);
    const senha = req.body.senha.substring(0,255);
    execSQLQuery(`UPDATE usuario SET Nome='${nome}', Email='${email}', Senha='${senha}' WHERE ID=${id}`, res);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.use('/', router);

//inicia o servidor
app.listen(port);
console.log('API funcionando!');

function execSQLQuery(sqlQry, res){
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'locadora'
  });

  connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, results, fields){
      if(error) 
        res.json(error);
      else
        res.json(results); //ERRO ACONTECE AQUI
      connection.end();
      console.log('executou!');
  });
}
```

Comment: Da pra indentificar a linha que aconteceu o problema no codigo que voce forneceu? Voce deu o numero mas nao da pra saber em qual codigo e em qual linha aqui.

Comment: connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, results, fields){
      if(error) 
        res.json(error);
      else
        res.json(results);
      connection.end();
      console.log('executou!');
  });  LINHA ->  res.json(results);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a mensagem de erro,

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

A resposta está sendo modificada depois de ter sido enviada. Olhando no código, você manda a resposta na função `execSQLQuery()`, então depois de chamar essa funcão, não podes mais modificar a sua `res`, como você está fazendo em `router.delete`, `.post`, e `.patch`.

Uma solução é passar o código de status http como argumento para `execSQLQuery()`, que irá usar o código quando enviar a resposta usando `res` lá.

Outra maneira é receber uma callback como parâmetro para execSQLQuery(), que você pode passar de onde você chamar a função, fornecendo o código para executar depois de rodar a query. Dessa maneira, você não precisa passar res como parâmetro para execSQLQuery(). Segue o exemplo:

```
function execSQLQuery(sqlQry, callback){
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'locadora'
  });

  connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, results, fields){
      if(error) 
        callback(error);
      else
        callback(null, results);
      connection.end();
      console.log('executou!');
  });
}
```

Chamada:

```
execSQLQuery(`INSERT INTO .........`, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500); // seta o status aqui
    return res.json(err);
  }
  res.status(200); // seta o status aqui (mas 200 deve ser padrao)
  res.json(result);
})
```

Comment: Funcionou retirando a linha res.sendStatus(200); de todos os metodos

Comment: @HenriqueHermes atualizei a resposta com exemplo do uso de callback, que e' o pattern usado no Nodejs originalmente.